# Visual studio code Jupyter + Julia

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia, plotly.js

I'm playing around with Julia and Jupyter extensions in VSCode. I'm also trying to use PlotlyJS to render some reports.

When I do this by default, I see this:

[image]

Basically, this is small and unreadable.

On the other hand, if I switch the MIME type like this:

[image]

It becomes much better in terms of size, but it screws up the x-axis labels:

[image]

So the question is - how to fix it? I need it to be big enough, and at the same time have normal labels :D

Comment: I believe both the title and the tags are misleading, as this is not a question on either VSCode or Jupyter, but about plotting... Also it is not clear what you want to represent graphically with such a large number of options.. maybe switch to a vertical layout and order the jobs incomes before plotting them...